# Use Angular constant outside of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it is not a good practice to use Angular services outside of angular but nevertheless it's very interesting for me, for example I have 
`.constant('APIprefix','/api')`

how can I retrieve **APIprefix** value outside of angular scope? For instance from other js file which is not in angular scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access any service like this:

```
angular.element(document.documentElement).injector().get('APIprefix');
```

Note that you should pass to `angular.element` DOM node where you put `ng-app`. In the example above `document.documentElement` is HTML tag.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nf8zhDsl1PAnE5zDYYaG?p=preview

Answer (score 7):

pixelbits example did not worked for me. I needed to do a small change to do it.

**Writting constants**

```
var app = angular.module('module',[]);
app.constant('APIprefix', '/api');
```

**Reading from non angular scope**

```
var prefix = angular.injector(['ng', 'module']).get('APIprefix');
```

Thanks pixelbits for showing me the way :)

Comment: I had to include ngRoute instead ng. But it works. Thanks for the hint :)